# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the two following python files and when i run it in python shell it works fine and prints decoded text but when i run it in pythonw.exe it has this error:

**error :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(lan.encodedtext.decode('utf-8'))
  File "C:\Python35\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: character maps to <undefined>
```

**main.py :**

```
from x.LV import lan
print(lan.encodedtext.decode('utf-8'))
```

**x \ LV.py:**

```
class Lan():
    def __init__(self):
        self.encodedtext = b'\xd8\xb3\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85'
lan = Lan()
```

also it works fine  in python shell and it works with `self.encodedtext = b'hello'`.